# How to delete files from a USB Stick ? Using File.delete() doesn't work

Tags: java, file-io

after creating a file and populating it with that with a thread if the file is in a USB java can't delete it, when I try on disk it deletes the file ok !

Here is the part of the code that create and after an exception when try to delete the file.

```
           if(canExport && fileCreated)
           {
              //Create the file
              this.file.createNewFile();

              //Export the data            
              this.run();

              if(possible == false){ // in case writing fails delete the file created.
                 file.delete();    

                 Export novaTentativa = new Export(plan);
                 novaTentativa.fileCreator(plan);                 
              }
           }
```

The file is created when the this.file.createNewFile() acts.

When **this.run()** runs, there is a lot of methods to populate the data and **handle exceptions**, if one exception is caught it sets the global **variable possible** to false so I know the file is created but empty in the USB, after that I try to delete it with file.delete();

Comment: If writing fails was the file created?

Comment: is there anything special about delete()? and how does your code know if the file failed?

Comment: have you checked the read/write rights? Maybe created file is read-only?

Comment: No I didn't check for read/write rights, how can I do that in Java ?

Comment: delete() is a File method to delete Files. If writing fails the file is created because you have to create the file first to be able to write to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mention that you're trying to delete the file "after an exception" - consequently, your approach is on the wrong track and isn't going to work as-is.

If an exception is thrown by earlier methods (e.g. the `createNewFile()` call), then that exception will immediately propagate upwards, so your `file.delete()` call won't get a chance to execute.  You'd need to wrap the earlier statements in a `try` block, and put the delete call in the corresponding `catch` or `finally` block in order for it to execute when an exception was thrown.

Here's an example of what you might try to do:

```
if(canExport && fileCreated)
{
    //Create the file
    this.file.createNewFile();

    try
    {
        this.run();
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        try
        {
            file.delete();
        }
        catch (IOException ignore) {} // don't want to mask the real exception

        // Rethrow the actual exception from run() so callers can handle it
        throw e;
    }
}
```

An alternative approach rather than catching `IOExceptions` would be to have a `finally` block (which is always run) and then check a condition there, such as your `possible` flag.

Note as well that I start the try block *after* the call to `createNewFile()` - if an exception is thrown in the create file call then the file won't exist to delete at all!

As a file note, adding "a lot of code that asks for the thread to start over" in your error-handling block is probably not the best design.  It would be more appropriate to simply consider recovering from IO situations here, and *let* the exception bubble up to the top and cause the thread/runnable to die.  The logic around restarting tasks and/or resurrecting threads would be better positioned with the class that started the threads in the first place (e.g. a thread pool/task executor/etc.).  Scattering the logic throughout the code will make it harder to see what any individual class is doing (not to mention that having a class marshall resources to resurrect *itself* just seems wrong from an OO standpoint).

Comment: I check for exception inside the thread that writes to the file, if one is caught it sets the **variable possible** to false to tell me if there was an error, the problem I think is with reading and writing permissions...                                             My error checking is working fine, the problem is deleting the file, the code gets there I've debugged and I am sure. but thanks for the response

Comment: About the OO design, this is called by a window, and in case the USB stick is full I need to present the window again to the user so he can choose a different path to write after he sees the error msg... that's the only reason it's there.

Comment: You probably want to check the boolean return value from `boolean deleted = File.delete( yourfile )` as well. `File.delete()` does **not** throw IOException if the delete fails.

Answer (score 0):

Try explicitly stating the drive letter, path and folder to access the USB device to create write and read or delete the file. If that does not work then it is possible only a specific operating system utility or proprietory utility can delete the file.

Comment: Don't think it cannot find the file because of that, because it can find it to create the empty file.

Answer (score 0):

How certain are you that you *closed* the file when the write failed?  I'll bet money that you are missing a finally block somewhere in this.run().  That would result in exactly the behavior you describe - delete() will fail if the file is open (you should check it's return code - File.delete() doesn't throw exceptions if it is unable to delete the file).

If you want to test this, replace this.run() with a super, crazy simple implementation that writes 100 bytes to the file, sets 'possible' to false, then returns.  If the file still won't delete, post the code you are using for this simplified version of run() and maybe someone can spot what's going on.